# Different import list of symbols for Debug and Release build

Tags: debugging, gcc, libstdc++

I can successfully build the same C++ code using GCC-8 for Debug (`-g -O0`) and Release (`-g -O2`) build.
I can successfully debug the Release-executable on a remote host, but I can't debug the Debug-executable on a remote host, because the Debug-executable imports an extra symbol `_ZNKSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEEcvbEv` from release version of libstdc++ which doesn't exist.

but I don't want to debug libstdc++, so I think I shouldn't install additional debug version of libstdc++.

it looks like a bug, or am I wrong?